# Generate pie chart with Gruff gem in Ruby

Tags: ruby, charts, gruff

I am attempting to create a pie chart using the `gruff` gem, but my chart is a black abyss regardless of what I do. This is my code:

```
association_disposition_pie_chart = Gruff::Pie.new
association_disposition_pie_chart.title = "Visual Pie Graph Test"
association_disposition_pie_chart.data 'Solved', 10
association_disposition_pie_chart.data 'Action Required', 50
    association_disposition_pie_chart.theme = {
      :colors => ['#A5D8D8', '#EFAD1C'],
      :font_color => 'black',
      :background_colors => 'white'
    }
association_disposition_pie_chart.write("association_disposition_pie_chart.jpg")
```

Why is this creating a black pie chart? The background is white, the font_color is black, but so is the entire chart. I want the chart pieces to be the colors specified in `:colors`.

## EDIT

Screenshot:

http://i39.tinypic.com/33ne1r6.jpg

Comment: Maybe this would help. Looks like your almost writing css there: http://gruff.rubyforge.org/classes/Gruff/Base.html#M000047

Answer (score 0):

This is mentioned in the documentation:

```
You can set a theme manually. Assign a hash to this method before you send your data.

graph.theme = {
  :colors => %w(orange purple green white red),
  :marker_color => 'blue',
  :background_colors => %w(black grey)
}
:background_image => 'squirrel.png' is also possible.

(Or hopefully something better looking than that.)
```

Although the source is more helpful:

```
# File 'lib/gruff/base.rb', line 300

def theme=(options)
  reset_themes()

  defaults = {
    :colors => ['black', 'white'],
    :additional_line_colors => [],
    :marker_color => 'white',
    :font_color => 'black',
    :background_colors => nil,
    :background_image => nil
  }
  @theme_options = defaults.merge options

  @colors = @theme_options[:colors]
  @marker_color = @theme_options[:marker_color]
  @font_color = @theme_options[:font_color] || @marker_color
  @additional_line_colors = @theme_options[:additional_line_colors]

  render_background
end
```

I think maybe the problem is your `colors` attribute - `:colors => ['#A5D8D8', '#EFAD1C']` - as [Shaun Frost Duke Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2811180/shaun-frost-duke-jackson) mentioned, it looks like you need to use [`add_color('#c0e9d3')`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/topfunky/gruff/Gruff/Base:add_color) to do that, but the documentation isn't clear where you do that if you're defining the theme in line.  It might be easier to add your own theme in the [`THEMES` module](https://github.com/topfunky/gruff/blob/master/lib/gruff/themes.rb):

```
LUIGIS_THEME = {
      :colors => [
        '#A5D8D8',
        '#EFAD1C'
      ],
      :marker_color => '#55ae36', 
      :font_color => 'black',
      :background_colors => 'white'
    }
```

which is then called with `g.theme = Gruff::Themes::LUIGIS_THEME`

Comment: This makes sense, and thanks for the tip. I went ahead and set that up, but I'm still running into the same issue. The data "labels" are showing up in the right colors, but the actual pie chart is still all black. When I switch to the default PASTEL theme the data labels again show up in pastel colors, but the pie chart is half white/half black. Any thoughts on why the chart isn't reflecting the data label colors?

Comment: could you add a screen shot to your post, perhaps?  have you tried playing around with the various attributes?  maybe set `:background_colors => %w(#d1edf5 white)` and see what happens?

Comment: I've tried that and a few other options, still striking out. I attached a screenshot of my most recent try. I tried passing in the Pastel theme with a few more parameters, and that creates the half white/half black chart. With only 2 data points it's still all black.

Comment: what about adding more colors to the `colors` array?

Comment: No dice. I've created no less than 100 different charts and graphs with the Gruff tool, not sure why I'm having such an issue with this pie chart...

Comment: huh...really strange.  i can't see any other possible problem, but actually i think i've used Gruff less than you.  maybe make a [new issue](https://github.com/topfunky/gruff/issues)?

Comment: Sure thing. Thanks for the help, I appreciate it. I'll post back here if I find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

While using imagemagick-no-hdri and the default rmagick gem the pie graphs would become black and white.  I was able to fix this issue by doing the following

```
Install imagemagick
git clone git@github.com:rmagick/rmagick.git
gem build rmagick.gemspec
gem install ./rmagick-2.13.2.gem
```

Comment: I will be testing this soon - Thanks for the tip.